# Unit testing a controller that resolves a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to write a test for my home module but I keep getting an error saying "unknown provider: service". If I change resolveSomething in my home module to return a string my app works so I know my resolve is working. I am just learning how to write tests so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Service**

```
angular.module( 'services', [])
.factory('service', function(){ 
    return {
        'users' : function(id) {
            return id; 
        }
    }
});
```

**Relevant part of Home**

```
angular.module('home', ['ui.router','services'])
.config(function config( $stateProvider, service) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'homeWithId', {
        url: '/home/:id',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        resolve:{
            resolveSomething: function() {
                return service.users(this.params.id);
            }
        }       
    })
})...
```

**Relevant part of Test... I think**

```
describe( 'Test home controller', function() {
    beforeEach( module( 'home' ) );
    beforeEach( module( 'services' ) );
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $location = $injector.get('$location');
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $state = $injector.get('$state');
        service = $injector.get('service');

        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

        createController = function() {
            return $controller('HomeCtrl', {
                '$scope': $scope,
                 resolveSomething: function() { console.log('resolveSomething'); },
                 service  : service
             });
        };
    ...
```

On a side note... I can access the service inside my controller with this test configuration if I simply return a string in the resolve.

**Home controller (works and testable)**

```
.controller( 'HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'resolveSomething','service', function( $scope, resolveSomething, service) {

    alert(service.users(1));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `service` is a service, not a provider. When you call `module.config()` you are only allowed to inject providers; your `service` hasn't been constructed yet. I believe what you need to do is to change your resolver to request the service as a dependency (I haven't worked with the UI state provider yet, so I might be wrong):

```
angular.module('home', ['ui.router','services'])
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'homeWithId', {
        url: '/home/:id',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        resolve:{
            resolveSomething: function(service) {
                return service.users(this.params.id);
            }
        }       
    });
});
```